# SQL performance optimization: AND vs IN

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Given this example table

```
+----+------+-----+--------+
| ID | Name | Age | Exempt |
+----+------+-----+--------+
|  1 | AA   |  50 | FALSE  |
|  2 | BB   |  40 | FALSE  |
|  3 | CC   |  30 | FALSE  |
|  4 | DD   |  65 | TRUE   |
|  5 | EE   |  50 | FALSE  |
|  6 | FF   |  20 | FALSE  |
+----+------+-----+--------+
```

And this query

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE AGE > 40 AND EXPEMPT = TRUE;
```

I've been told that I could optimize this query having a subquery, but also having an IN statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE AGE > 40 AND ID IN (SELECT ID 
                          FROM USERS WHERE EXEMPT = TRUE);
```

That could work but I can't understand why the second query is better than the first one in performance.

Comment: With `AND` all rows have to evaluate the `WHERE` condition. With the subquery, first the table gets filtered by the `EXEMPT` field, and only the resulted rows (in this case only one row) gets to the "second run" and has to be filtered by the `AGE` column... This would gain performance, if the table has more rows, lik a few hundred thousands...

Comment: However an index on `(EXEMPT, AGE DESC)` would provide almost as much performance gain...

Comment: Do you have primary keys, indexes on your table. Share your create table statement

Comment: What DBMS are you speaking of? Where is the execution plan?

Comment: TBH, there is no DBMS, nor schema, nor key, nor indexes.. This is based in a theorical class I had some days ago. I tried this in a PostgreSQL with +200K rows and the first one seems to be more efficient, which confused me most since
A) They seem to be same effiency for me
B) We arrived the conclussion in class that the second one is more efficient
C) Another option (using subquery) could be the most performant theorically but is the slowest in postgreSQL so, my question is not oriented to one specific DBMS since they could change the performance

Comment: "This is based in a theorical class" --- then the question does not have answer: every DBMS (and every version of a particular DBMS) has different performance characteristics.

Comment: I know, that kinds of upsets me the most. Anyways, I expected to have some performance principles that are cross-DBMS, and I thought this was one of that principles..For example: I knew that If I had
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EXEMPT = TRUE;)
WHERE AGE > 40;`
It would have a better performance, without going into DBMS characteristics, because it would filter the exempt users first and then it would apply the "where age > 40" only in the filtered table,  going on with only 1 row

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no circumstances where the second query would be better than the first.  The second requires scanning `users` and then doing additional work with the `id`; the first just requires scanning `users`.  If the second can take advantage of an index or data partition, the first should be able to use the same index or data partition.

If you wanted to speed the query, then an index on `(exempt, age)` might be useful.

Do note that performance considerations on a table with 6 rows are generally meaningless -- all reasonable queries should be pretty fast on so few rows.